# Mini-cart changes not taking effect - Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, caching, themes, magento2

I need to change mini-cart in our theme that falls back to magento 2 luna theme to show it using hover instead of click.

So I have copied

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

to

```
/app/design/frontend/[ourCompany]/[websitename]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

Edited the file:

```
....
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "triggerEvent" : "hover",
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
....
```

Cleared cache, flushed cache, refreshed cache types, cleared static content, deleted everything generated and cached from /var...

Then I re-run static content deploy. Enabled template path hints which shows that minicart.phtml is loaded from:

```
/app/design/frontend/[ourCompany]/[websitename]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/
```

So it's fine. But on the website the changes has not take change. So I have checked the

```
/var/view_prepro.../app/design/frontend/[ourCompany]/[websitename]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

Changes of the file are not there. So I have made more changes (added some html)... Cleared cache, flushed cache, refreshed cache types, cleared static content, deleted everything generated and cached from /var...

Then I re-run static content deploy.

Still no changes on the website.

When I changed something in Mage_Catalog or other modules everything just worked fine.

I am using Magento 2.1.5

Thank you for any possible solutions, ideas,...

Comment: have you tried to make your changes using developer mode? just a guess.. maybe you're in production mode and some advanced caching is running. even though it seems strange if for some other modules is working...

Comment: Yes, i was working in developer mode. Then in the end I have also tried to switch to production mode, regenerate and clear all possible caches. But did not helped. Then i switched back to developer mode. Did a upgrade to Magento 2.1.9, cleared flushed everything.. but changes still not working. I cant get it that if Path Hints shows correct file, why the outputted file content is different/wrong

Comment: I'm on Magento 2.1.7. I managed to make changes happen to minicart editing the vendor template (just as a try). Actually the changest to the html appear only if I visit the checkout/cart page, but not from the home page. Guess it's a problem of template. I alsto tried to disable the magento_pageCache extension, but it doesn't seem to cause problems btw. As soon as i have some time i will try the "right" way and check if it works too.

Comment: uh and also check your compilation mode, and set to server-side compilation. (if you don't want to make it by yourself)

Comment: Thanks. Problem is solved, don't know how, but I have re-done today again the full process of clearing cache, re-compiling,... and it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved, don't know how, but I have re-done today again the full process of clearing cache, re-compiling... and it started to work.

Comment: well good for you :) but magento's magic is not so good really as it often happens...

Comment: Yeah. Now when I am trying to create shopping cart price rule aka coupon, i select a date and i get please enter a valid date... I miss old magento 1.9 where everything worked as it needed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Hope it might be useful.

Sid

Comment: As I metioned in the question, "Cleared cache, flushed cache, refreshed cache types, cleared static content, deleted everything generated and cached from /var... Then I re-run static content deploy." So your answer is not helpful. Also this question is already answered and also it was like 2 years ago. But it might be helpful to other people.

Comment: Yes @ErikKubica
I appreciate your response. 
But it might be useful for some other people who looking for same things.